# Add Different Event Listeners For Different Slot Content with Web Components

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

Below is a web component written in vanilla js. It is a general component that is a modal drawer, it has a simple job, to open and close.

How would this generic component be able to utilize different event listeners based on its content? For example, if a login form was put into the modal, then how could we add a `submit` event to the slot content in the shadow dom? If a reset password form was in the modal, then we would need a different `submit` event.

If the content was a form, and the slot had a submit event listener on it, could the event listener for the slot be removed in the disconnected callback?

```js
const button = document.querySelector('.modal-btn')

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const modal = document.createElement('drawer-modal')
    document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(modal)
  })
  
  
  const template = document.createElement('template')
  template.innerHTML = `
    <style>
      .modal {
      z-index: 9;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .modal-mask {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      left: 0;
      z-index: 9;
      transition: opacity 0.4s ease-in-out;
      background-color: rgba(0 0 0 / 50%);
      opacity: 0;
    }

    .modal-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      z-index: 10;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: flex-end;
      transition: transform 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transform: translateY(100%);
    }

    .modal-inner {
      position: static;
      flex: 0 0 auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      background: #fff;
      padding: 24px;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="modal">
      <div class="modal-mask"></div>
      <div class="modal-wrapper">
        <div class="modal-inner">
          <!--
           if this was a slot with form content, how
           would an event listener for submit be added and 
           how would that same event listener be removed
           in disconnected callback?
          -->  
          <slot name="content"></slot>
          <p>click on the mask to close the modal</p>
        </div>  
      </div>  
    </div>
  `

  class DrawerModal extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
      super()

      this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' })
      this.shadowRoot.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true))

      this.wrapper = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.modal-wrapper')
      this.mask = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.modal-mask')
      this.content = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('.modal-inner')

      this.wrapper.addEventListener('click', this.closeModal)
      this.content.addEventListener('click', this.stopPropagation)
    }

    connectedCallback() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.wrapper.style.transform = 'translateY(0%)'
        this.mask.style.opacity = '1'
      })
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
      this.wrapper.removeEventListener('click', this.closeModal)
      this.content.removeEventListener('click', this.stopPropagation)
    }

    closeModal = e => {
      this.wrapper.style.transform = 'translateY(100%)'
      this.mask.style.opacity = '0'
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.remove()
      }, 400)
    }

    stopPropagation = e => {
      e.stopPropagation()
    }

  }
  window.customElements.define('drawer-modal', DrawerModal)
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>modal test</h1>
  <button class="modal-btn">open modal</button>
  <div id="app"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Example 1**

Here a form is being inserted into the modal drawer, this needs a `submit event`, can we add the `submit event` inside the drawer components `connectedCallback` and remove the event listener in the `disconnectedCallback`?

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modal = document.createElement('drawer-modal')
  modal.innerHTML = `
    <form slot="content">
      <label for="email>email</label>
      <input type="text" id="email">
    </form>
  `
  document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(modal)
})
```

**Example 2**

Here a button is being inserted into the modal drawer and needs a click event listener.

```js
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const modal = document.createElement('drawer-modal')
  modal.innerHTML = `
    <button slot="content" class="btn">click me</button>
  `
  document.querySelector('#app').appendChild(modal)
})
```

Comment: I do not 100% grasp your question; does the [slotchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event) Event not work for your use-case?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman No, that won't work. The above is just a modal drawer that opens and closes so my question is if we added content to it how we could add specific listeners based on the content that is added, and also how could we remove them. Right now I keep thinking of needing a ton of if checks in the connected callback and I don't think that's the way to go.

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I just edited my question a bit for clarity, see if that explains it better please

Comment: Maybe I still don't understand. Slotted content is **reflected** in ``<slot>``, thus the click handlers need to be on the original elements, which a component _can_ assign/set since the elements are in its lightDOM. Looks to me you want to create a swiss army knife; yes your component then needs to process anything that _can_ be slotted. Note; removing listeners is only required when JS Garbage Collection doesn't remove them (like the ones you may have attached to ``document``). In your above examples GC will remove any listeners when the Web Compoment is removed from the DOM.

Comment: Yes exactly, there are elements in the light dom that need specific event listeners and the elements in the light dom could change per instance of the component since it's a dynamically added modal. With this current implementation, you mentioned that the component needs to process anything that can be slotted, this means in the component you would need a bunch of if checks to make certain decisions and that was my main question if there would be a way around this. Would the component need to dispatch a custom `close` event that the light dom element would subscribe to?

Comment: If your Web Component needs be able to process scenarios A,B,C,D and E. You then need to program them all. And maybe A,D and E have similarities you can program once. That is why I say you are creating a swiss-army-knife. [_A picture says more than a thousand words_](https://i.imgur.com/N3mRBpL.png)

Comment: Maybe check `event.composedPath()` and see if it contains any `form` element, if so then should be a submit event?